# Using FormAssembly and Marketing Cloud trying to prefill

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a embedded form using Formassembly and based on the URL it will retrieved existing info for SalesCloud. If I hard-code in an email and Lead ID it works trying to figure out the ampscript syntax to retrieve the Lead ID and email so that I can use it in the URL:

```
<iframe id="content"  src="https://TheFormAssemblyURL?leadEmail={!Lead.Email}&leadID={!Lead.Id}" height="800" width="600"
frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

The above would be sent to a subscriber via MC email template once we can query the email and Lead ID FormAssembly will retrieve the rest of the info.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 %%[ var @rs
set @Email = QueryParameter("emailaddress")
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, 'Email', '=', @Email)
Set @row = ROW(@rs,1)
Set @Id = FIELD(@row,"Id")
]%%



<iframe id="content"  src="https://TheFormAssemblyURL?leadEmail={%%=v(@Email)=%%}&leadID={%%=v(@Id)=%%}" height="800" width="600"
frameborder="0" ></iframe>
<script src="//tfaforms.com/js/iframe_resize_helper.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a field and a quote in your retrieve AMPScript.

I'm assuming this code is in a landing/microsite page.  You can't use an `iframe` or JavaScript in an email.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
%%[ 
var @rs, @email, @row, @id
set @Email = QueryParameter("emailaddress")
Set @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id,Email','Email','=', @Email)

if rowcount(@rs) > 0 then

    Set @row = ROW(@rs,1)
    Set @Id = FIELD(@row,"Id")
    ]%%

    <iframe id="content"  src="https://TheFormAssemblyURL?leadEmail={%%=v(@Email)=%%}&leadID={%%=v(@Id)=%%}" height="800" width="600"
    frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    <script src="//tfaforms.com/js/iframe_resize_helper.js"></script>

%%[
else 
  outputline(concat("<br>lead not found"))
endif
]%%

</body>
</html>
```

**Reference**

- [**RetrieveSalesforceObjects()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)
- [**Limitations of HTML email**](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email)