# Embedding a FormAssembly form into CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Is it possible to embedd a FormAssembly form into a CloudPage?

I can't find any official, or otherwise, documentation that says that it can.

We currently have a CloudPage that uses a Smart Capture form that is collecting data and triggering a Journey.  The only problem is, it is writing the email address into the SubscriberKey.  We'd like to use FormAssembly's functionality to check if the record exists currently in Sales Cloud, if it does then use the record's existing GUID as the SubscriberKey.  If the record doesn't exist then we need to create a new GUID for the SubscriberKey.

Full disclosure, I've never used FormAssembly before and only know that it can perform the above actions on the advice of a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that without FormAssembly, it's just a bit of AMPscripting with [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) function to perform a check for any existing Leads or Accounts and then deciding if it's worth storing to Data Extension.

It will probably require using a custom AMPscript solution instead of standard Form Capture feature though.

To do things in a proper way, I would advise to set the process up in following way:

- Form Submit checks if Sales Cloud record has the Email Address on some record.
- If Email exists -- retrieve the SF ID and insert the record with this SF ID to Journey (if required)
- If Email doesn't exist -- create the Lead record in SF with a specific tag and then insert this Lead record with fresh SF ID to Journey.

That being said, if you want to use FormAssembly forms, then yes, then you can do it via iFrame, as seen on this [**SFSE topic**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170632/using-formassembly-and-marketing-cloud-trying-to-prefill).